# How to automatically trigger click event with shepherd tour

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have set up a page tour using a Shepherd tour. I am trying to apply click events whenever the tour reaches a specific section. However, I am not able to trigger click events automatically.

```html
buildPageTour() {
        let tour = this.tour;
        
        const step1 = tour.addStep({
            id: 'guidedDashboard1',
            text: '<h5>Hello!</h5>',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Skip',
                    action: tour.cancel,
                    secondary: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Next',
                    action: tour.next
                }
            ]
        });
        const step2 = tour.addStep({
            id: 'guidedDashboard2',
            text: 'Page tour 2',
            attachTo: {
                element: '.orientationStepArea',
                on: 'bottom'
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Skip',
                    action: tour.cancel, 
                    secondary: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Back',
                    classes: 'backBt',
                    action: tour.back
                },
                {
                    text: 'Next',
                    action: tour.next
                }
            ]
        });
   }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

So now when the page tour reaches the 2nd section, I want to trigger a click event for my toggle menu so that the page tour appears on the correct icon.

```html
<div class="helpMenu" data-bind="css: {expanded: showMenu()}">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- ko if: hasPageTour() -->
            <div class="item" data-bind="click: launchPageTour, clickBubble: false">
                <svg class="ico"><use xlink:href="Content/icons/icons.svg#infoBaloon" /></svg>
                <span class="label">Page Tour</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: realTimeFeedbackEnabled() -->
            <div class="item" id="vFooterShareFeedback" data-bind="click: launchRealTimeFeedbackSurvey, clickBubble: false">
                <svg class="ico"><use xlink:href="Content/icons/icons.svg#notes" /></svg>
                <span class="label">Share Feedback</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="item" data-bind="click: openDialog, clickBubble: false">
                <svg class="ico"><use xlink:href="Content/icons/icons.svg#email" /></svg>
                <span class="label">Contact Support</span>
            </div>
            <div class="item -close" data-bind="click: hideHelpMenu, clickBubble: false">
                <svg class="ico"><use xlink:href="Content/icons/icons.svg#close" /></svg>
                <span class="label">CLOSE</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare action as a function, and use vanilla javascript to click the element.

```
  buttons: [
    {
      action () {
        const selector = document.getElementById('my-id-example')
        selector.click()
        return this.next()
      },
      text: 'Continue'
    }
  ]
```